# fatal: remote server hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, bash, ssh, github

I've looked at the other threads with similar questions, but I'm new to git, so most of it didn't make sense :(

Here's the problem:

I can't push a simple readme onto my repository on github.

`$ ssh -T git@github.com` seems to be working fine.

But whenever I push the README using the following:

```
$ git push origin master
```

I get the following error -

```
ssh: connect to host githum.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Notice that it says the host is 'githum.com'. So I must have made a typo when I was setting up the ssh keys for git. How do I correct this and make sure the remote end works properly?

Comment: Check your `.gitconfig`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a file in `.git` directory, `config`. You can fix it there. (You can edit the same with `git config -e`).

Or use the command to fix the origin:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:path/to/repo
```

Answer (score 4):

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:user/test.git
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have set the ssh url for the origin wrong when adding the remote. Do:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:user/repo
```

to correct.

Or just do `git config -e` or `vim .git/config` and correct the url in the config directly under `[remote "origin"]`